# Django url template tag ovrwrite the last letter of the base address

Tags: python, django, templates, url, tags

When using the URL template tag I checked the source code of the html page and the url appears missing the last letter of the base address, see an example:
...

```
<li><a href="{% url 'product' %}">Products</a></li>
```

...
returns
...

```
<li><a href="/dec/product/">Products</a></li>
```

...
but the the base address is my-site.com/deck
...
so, why dont returns
...

```
<li><a href="/deck/product/">Products</a></li>
```

...

I checked my **settings.py** and **urls.py** and didn't see anything wrong, I don't know where else to look

my urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('principal.urls')),
    path('product/', include('products.urls'), name='product'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and the urls.py from app product

```
from django.urls import path    
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductHTMxTableView.as_view(), name='products'),
    path('product/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
    path('show/', views.ProductShow.as_view(), name='product_show'),

]
```

Comment: Please share your `urls.py` file too.

Comment: Please share your urls file, the issue might be in your url configurations

Comment: You way of using the namespace in the include is wrong `path('product/', include('products.urls'), name='product'),`. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) on how to do it properly.